# IE not rendering DatePicker for MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, datepicker

I´m making an MVC5 site, as you already know. And now I just created a View using Crete template that has a BirthDate Field. Andit is not showing in IE and shows horibly in Chrome with lots of gliphs inside the textbox as you can compare in the image below.

[image]

What is going on and how can I make IE to show a date picker just as easy as Chrome does, and how to clena it up a bit. Those levers I think are useless and confusing.

Here is how I defined that property in my model

```
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de nacimiento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

and in the View

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't like the built in datepicker (which is being rendered by the browser because it is input type="date"), then there are plenty of 3rd party plugins available such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com).

One thing you will need to potentially change is instead of using `EditorFor` you might need to use `TextBoxFor` so the browser just treats it as a normal text box. Below is an example using jQuery UI:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate)

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#BirthDate').datepicker();
    });
```

Comment: But Why IE is not showing any Date Picker, that´s one the questions I intended. How can Imakeit work. this is IE10 running on Win8.

Comment: I'm not sure IE10 has full support of HTML 5. Check http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date

Comment: No they don´t :( what do they all day long? SO I´mgoing with jquery. Letyou know and mark as answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Dissmissile I figure it out with bootstrap datepicker but a bit different in my view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

then I added the next js code to configure format and behaviour

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            autoclose: true
        });
        $(".datepicker").datepicker('setValue', new Date());
    });
```